# How can I change paragraph content on button click with if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Trying to display different messages inside the p element for when someone clicks on one of the three buttons. But it only displays the first message (reply) for all the buttons.

Can't see what I have done wrong...

**HTML**

```
<div class="options">
   <div id="good" class="btn"></div>
   <div id="idk" class="btn"></div>
   <div id="bad" class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let good = document.getElementById("good");
let idk = document.getElementById("idk");
let bad = document.getElementById("bad");
let main = document.querySelector(".main");
let reply;

document.getElementById("good"), document.getElementById("idk"), document.getElementById("bad")].forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (good.clicked = true) {
          main.style.display = "block";
          reply = "Hey";
        } else if (idk.clicked = true) {
          main.style.display = "block";
          reply = "Well yeah";
        } else if (bad.clicked = true) {
          main.style.display = "block";
          reply = "123";
        }
        document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = reply;
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please add the full example with the html too ?

Comment: Change clicked = true for clicked == true

Comment: Sure @NicolaeMaties

Comment: Tried it, did not work. @Marc

Comment: @KarimZ see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const good = document.getElementById("good");
const idk = document.getElementById("idk");
const bad = document.getElementById("bad");
const main = document.querySelector(".main");
const reply = document.getElementById("reply");

const messageTypes = {
  good: 'Hey',
  idk: 'Well yeah',
  bad: '123 BAD'
};

[good, idk, bad].forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    reply.innerHTML = messageTypes[e.target.id];
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="options">
<button id="good" class="btn">good</button>
<button id="idk" class="btn">idk</button>
<button id="bad" class="btn">bad</button>
</div>
<div class="main"><div>
<div id="reply"></div>
```

Use const for everything, create a separate message dictionary for every message and just map it against the id. You don't need to use jQuery.

Comment: I don't know why the code doesn't work in my js file. I don't get any error either.

Comment: Try to add logs, to see where is the issue. Make sure your are correctly referencing the js file inside the html one.

Answer (score 1):

If your real use case is as simple as your example, I would consider maybe using different event listeners with different logic inside them. But if you want to use the same event listener, then you can use `event.target.id` to know which button was clicked:

```
[document.getElementById("good"), document.getElementById("idk"), document.getElementById("bad")].forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case "good":
        reply = "Hey";
        break;
      case "idk":
        reply = "Well yeah";
        break;
      case "bad":
        reply = "123";
        break;
    }
    main.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = reply;
  });
});
```

Here you can see it working (note that I removed `main.style.display = "block";` in the following example since I don't know what `main` is in your original code):

```js
[document.getElementById("good"), document.getElementById("idk"), document.getElementById("bad")].forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case "good":
        reply = "Hey";
        break;
      case "idk":
        reply = "Well yeah";
        break;
      case "bad":
        reply = "123";
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = reply;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="options">
<div id="good" class="btn">good</div>
<div id="idk" class="btn">idk</div>
<div id="bad" class="btn">bad</div>
</div>
<div id="reply"/>
```

Comment: Your example works when I run code snippet, but does not work in my js file

Comment: I Imagine that maybe you're using different id's or something like that?

Comment: No, it's exactly like yours.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's developer console?

Comment: No, made it work a "little", will try to fix it myself for now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful. Feel free to ask any further questions

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like that:

```js
let good = document.getElementById("good");
    let idk = document.getElementById("idk");
    let bad = document.getElementById("bad");
    let main = document.querySelector(".main");
    let reply;

    [good, idk, bad].forEach(option => {
      option.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (e.target == good) {
          main.style.display = "block";
          reply = "Hey";
        } else if (e.target == idk) {
          main.style.display = "block";
          reply = "Well yeah";
        } else if (e.target == bad) {
          main.style.display = "block";
          reply = "123";
        }
        document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = reply;
      });
    });
```

```html
<div class="options">
<div id="good" class="btn">good</div>
<div id="idk" class="btn">idk</div>
<div id="bad" class="btn">bad</div>
</div>
<div class="main"><div>
<div id="reply"></div>
```

Comment: Your example works when I run code snippet, but does not work in my js file

Comment: @KarimZ Which error have you? I've added two random divs (main and replay) but were not on your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead, do something like this for what you want

In Pure VanillaJS

```
[document.getElementById("good"), document.getElementById("idk"), document.getElementById("bad")].forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.target.id == "good") {
      main.style.display = "block";
      reply = "Hey";
    } else if (event.target.id == "idk") {
      main.style.display = "block";
      reply = "Well yeah";
    } else if (event.target.id == "bad") {
      main.style.display = "block";
      reply = "123";
    }
    document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = reply;
  });
});
```

Comment: Is that jquery? If so I want to do it with vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used for assignments however `==` is used to check equality of two strings in javascript

```
   [] ...addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (good.id == e.target.id) {
      main.style.display = "block";
      reply = "Hey";
    } 
    // and so on
    document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = reply;
  });
```

```js
var btn1=document.getElementById('btn1')
var btn2=document.getElementById('btn2')
var btn3=document.getElementById('btn3')
// jquery way
$('.btn').on("click",function(e){
    $("#msg").html(e.target.id+" clicked");
})
// javascript way
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){  
     document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML =e.target.id+' clicked';
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="btn" value="button 1">
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn" value="button 2">
<input type="button" id="btn3" class="btn" value="button 3">
<p id="msg"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use explicit event handlers for each of the buttons rather than a generic handler that then tests all three conditions.

You can reduce the code duplication by using a function to handle the display update of the `main` element and the setting of `reply`.

Something like the following shows this in action:

```js
let good = document.getElementById("good");
let idk = document.getElementById("idk");
let bad = document.getElementById("bad");
let main = document.querySelector(".main");

good.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showMain("Good");
});

idk.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showMain("Well yeah");
});

bad.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showMain("123");
});

function showMain(replyText) {
  main.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = replyText;
}
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="good">Good</button>
<button id="idk">Idk</button>
<button id="bad">Bad</button>
<div class="main"></div>
<div id="reply"></div>
```